# EE layout logic

Tags: html, content-management-system, expressionengine

We are a church with four different locations: let’s call them North, South, East and West.  Now, each of these locations has ‘Ministries:’ Let’s call them Man, Boy, Woman, Girl.

Here’s where the problem lies, not all of the locations have all of the same ‘Ministries.’  Basically, I’m setting the backend up in EE to where ‘Ministries’ is a channel, and I created a category group called ‘Locations’ that holds North, South, East and West as categories.  I then set up a static template for North, South, East and West so that the URL will look like site.com/north/ministries/man, etc…  My problem is I can’t figure out how to get category linking to work.  For example, under my North template page, I make a call to show all entries that hold the ‘Man’ category.  The only problem is that I’m not sure where I can send the link for ‘Man’ once the user clicks it.  For instance, whatever URL the user clicks on from the category needs to know that the category was sent from the ‘North’ location because the content for each ‘Ministry’ is different depending on which location it’s in.  Any idea’s would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the [related_categories_mode](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/parameters.html#related_categories_mode).

Comment: What does the current outputted URL look like? I'm not sure what you mean by "send the link".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rjb and @Stephanie, thanks for your comments.  I finally decided that using the Multi-Site Manager to turn each campus into it's own 'site' in a sub-folder of the main site was the practical way to go, since each campus is likely going to have a large amount of unique content in the future.

Since they're separated by 'site' now, it's super easy using categories to relate content, since it's all going to be properly related now.  Thanks again.